# How to reduce the number of DB hits in Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

This might be a very general question. I want to know if caching (first level cache and second level cache) is this the only way to reduce the number of db hits in Hibernate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very generic, however at a high level yes caching will solve multiple database hit problem. You can use hibernate caching also you can also use **Spring Cache Abstraction** for a fine grained implementation. There are other aspects also and that depends on your problem statement and solution approach.

Remember: Any caching will increase your memory uses in application and also you need to clean cache appropriately to avoid any stale information being used.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing a number of DB queries can be divided into 2 steps:

1. Eliminating possible N + 1 problem sources.
2. Looking for hot spots in the application, what data is nedeed the most often and cache it by various means.

The former could be done with @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT), JPQL/HQL **JOIN FETCH** and JPA entity graphs. For the latter you can use Spring caching possibilities or Hibernate-specific caching.

Comment: could you explain on 'The former could be done with @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELET), JPQL/HQL JOIN FETCH and JPA entity graph' ?